# How to Change the DataContext between multiple views from sideView

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a Project with Multiple views and found this tutorial at Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUwk2-_tRzo. This works so fare fine but i face a problem by trying to change the DataContent out of a second view.
I create a Button on the blueview.xaml and try to change with the click event the `DataContent` to the red view but it doesn’t work.
I try to access the DataContext from the MainWindow by `MainWindow.Datacontext= new blueView();` but this also don’t work.

I tried to create

```
class  PageSwitch : InotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
        private object acView = null;
        public object AcValue
        {
            get { return acView; }
            set { acView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("acView");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyNam)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyNam));
        }
```

In my Side window I create a instand from this class like

```
PageSwitch pageswitch = new PageSwitch();
```

and in my MainWindow.xaml I bind

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding AcValue, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />
```

It works if I set the ACValue in

```
public MainWindow()  
{
InitializeComponent();
pageswitch.AcValue= new RedView();
Datacontent = pageswitch.
}
```

but if i try to change the AcValue after that with a Button Click like `pageswitch.AcValue = new Overview();`
nothing happens. Why my view is not updating if the AcView Value is changing?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
We can't really advise you how to fix your code if we can't see it.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest approach is to have a property in your mainwindowviewmodel which is (say) CurrentViewModel.

Switch that out for your different viewmodels.

Data template into UI.

The below code uses the community toolkit mvvm, which has code generators.

There's a list of viewmodels which are bound to a listbox on the left of the view, similar to that video.
You click one it fires a command in mainwindowviewmodel which instantiates that viewmodel by type. It caches the instance in a dictionary for re-use later in case you want to retain state between navigation.

That viewmodel is presented via currentviewmodel to the right column in the view.
The datatemplates in mainwindow then template that into ui with the viewmodel as datacontext.

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string mainWinVMString = "Hello from MainWindoViewModel";

    [ObservableProperty]
    private object currentViewModel = null;

    [ObservableProperty]
    List<TypeAndDisplay> navigationViewModelTypes = new List<TypeAndDisplay>
        {
           new TypeAndDisplay{ Name="Yellow", VMType= typeof(YellowViewModel) },
           new TypeAndDisplay{ Name="Blue", VMType= typeof(BlueViewModel) }
        };

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Navigate(Type vmType)
    {
        CurrentViewModel = null;
        if (viewModels.ContainsKey(vmType))
        {
            CurrentViewModel = viewModels[vmType];
            return;
        }
        CurrentViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(vmType);
        viewModels.Add(vmType, CurrentViewModel);
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, Object> viewModels = new Dictionary<Type, Object>();
}
```

MainWindow

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YellowViewModel}">
        <local:YellowUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BlueViewModel}">
        <local:BlueUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationViewModelTypes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding VMType}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                      Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
                          />
</Grid>
```

You can pull and take a look at it working from:

https://github.com/AndyONeill/WPF_NavigationViewModelFirst/tree/master

Comment: Hello Andy, first of all thank you for your Help!
Unfortunately I'm quite unskilled and don’t get it done. I don’t really understand it at all and your recommence modification even less
Do you know a step by step tutorial were I can see the entire way, or can you explain it in more smaller steps?!